# How should I store user "favorites" in mySQL table?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I keep reading that I should store this in a separate table "with one value per line". What does this mean exactly? Like this - So that each "favoriting" gets another user entry?

```
USER_ID     SKU_Favorited

001         10016
001         10067
024         10016
001         10010
024         16779
```

Seems redundant to have to enter the same user twice, but is this what I should do? Then in lookup I just `SELECT` sku `WHERE` user id... and find all SKUs next to that number?

Comment: How would you do it instead?

Comment: This is known as a ManyToMany relation and normal practice. You don't have redundant users, because all the user data is in the User table and not the Favourite table

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is called relational databases that are in 3-rd normal form

You have one table with users.

```
//users
id | username | password
```

And table with favorites

```
//favorites
id | userid | Favorited
```

here how you get it:

`select * from favorites inner join users on favorites.userid=users.id where users.id=1`

Comment: So for each favorite sku there will be a new entry, correct? so skus and user ids will repeat throughout the table?

Comment: According to me, the favorites table should not have an ID. (userid, Favorited) has to be the primary key.

Comment: @frankie: Well, same userid and same sku in one entry should be unique. Other than that, this is correct.

Comment: @gd1, I prefer to add auto-incremental ID, and actually the timestamp with auto-value `now()` to all tables. But your approach is correct as well.

Comment: @Andrew how  would you do a normal query and check for any results that might be marked by the user as a favorite?

Comment: I was wondering why you would include the id (primary key) row for favorites. Would it be sufficient to leave that out because you could always uniquely identify the favorite by the userid and the SKU?