# How to produce json output with array of text instead of text

Tags: php, json

I created a mySQL database with phpMyAdmin in my local server. In this database I stored the names and their favourite NBA teams (along with an id as a primary key for the database). I wrote and run the following php script to retrieve these data from the database and project them on my local web server (XAMPP):

```
<?php

$dbServername = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'Friends';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM friends;';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$arr = [];
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

However, in this way I take this json output:

```
[...,
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "David Belton",
    "team": "["Boston Celtics", "Houston Rockets"]"
},
...]
```

But I would like to take the following json output:

```
[...,
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "David Belton",
    "team": ["Boston Celtics", "Houston Rockets"]
},
...]
```

Therefore I want to take `[Boston Celtics", "Houston Rockets"]` for `"team"` which is an array instead of `"[Boston Celtics", "Houston Rockets"]"` which is text.

Note that in the column team in the database the values are stored as `["Boston Celtics", "Houston Rockets"]` (not json) which is text/string.

How can I do this easily with PHP?

Comment: How are the teams stored int he database?

Comment: Are the team arrays stored as a string in the database?

Comment: So you want the team property in your output to be a string not an array!

Comment: Poete_Maudit has described its database here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294704

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, I have stored it as text in the database.

Comment: Thanks also for the link. I have made this question so I have this in my mind however I was thinking that it was getting too complex so I thought that I could do it directly in a csv file and then just import in the database as such.

Comment: Sorry give me one minute please because I may do something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like json (though broken), you could decode it before applying it to the array.

Like:

```
$arr = [];
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row['team'] = json_decode($row['team'])
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

But if it's not json, you might need to do more work.. This is why you should normalise the database and not store multiple values in the same column.

Comment: I tested and it works (if I am not doing it wrong). Apologies to the other user who has suggested a similar solution but I falsely dismissed it.